# Javascript How to group data by similar values

Tags: javascript, typescript, lodash

Say I have some data like this:

```
[ {...otherData, coordinates: {x: 2022, y: 149832}}, {...otherData, coordinates: {x: 2023, y: 153729}}, {...otherData, coordinates: {x: 2024, y: 156800}}, {...otherData, coordinates: {x: 2024, y: 195233}}, {...otherData, coordinates: {x: 2035, y: 341978}} ]
```

I want to group the most similar values together using the x and y keys. The output looking something like this:

```
[ [{...otherData, coordinates: {x: 2022, y: 149832}}, {...otherData, coordinates: {x: 2023, y: 153729}}, {...otherData, coordinates: {x: 2024, y: 156800}}], [ {...otherData, coordinates: {x: 2024, y: 195233}}, {...otherData, coordinates: {x: 2035, y: 341978}}] ]
```

The array returned will contain nested arrays, each containing grouped data, and a final array containing the data that couldn't be grouped.

To set the range of what counts as similar, let's say the x values have to be within 1 year of each other. If that check passes then the follow up check is for the y values. They need to be within 10,000 of each other.  I've thought about using reduce for this but honestly I keep drawing a blank on what the logic would look like.

**Explanation for those who are curious:**

The purpose behind this is that eventually I'll use them on a scatter chart. The issue is that the data coming in will have points that end up overlapping in clusters of dots. Rather than a cluster, I'm hoping to aggregate similar values of data and within those groups, select the one with the lowest y value, and plot that to the graph. When you tap on that plot point a small graphic will appear containing the remaining values from that group.

Answer (score 0):

One of things I loved when I used C# is `LINQ` - the ability to make queries other data sets without using a DB.

I know that we are using `javascript` here and also - hope we all understand that as a rule of thumb - queries over large datasets should be handled via a db (SQL-based is preferred)

Saying that - there are lots of `LINQ` libraries for `javascript` as well, and if you decide that you want to manipulate tour queries over client-side (for instance) - you can use one of this libraries as well (In person, I used [this one](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linq) in several projects)

### The benefits:

- Save resources and move loads from your DB / backend service to your client (if your data is relatively slim and not over-loading your traffic from back to front)
- You can use `LINQ` resources to ease your development (it's almost as easy as copy-and-paste with light adjustments)
- Make fast data transitions - improve UX

Here's a quick example to help you get started:

```
const data = [ { coordinates: {x: 2022, y: 149832}}, {coordinates: {x: 2022, y: 153729}}, {coordinates: {x: 2024, y: 156800}}, { coordinates: {x: 2024, y: 195233}}, {coordinates: {x: 2035, y: 341978}} ]

const groupByResults = Enumerable.from(data).groupBy(item => item.coordinates.x).toArray()

const group = groupByResults[0] // this is for demonstration purposes only
console.log(group.key(), group.getSource())
```